how the multiplicative property of MGF implies independence of random variables

Given $(X, Y) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ be 2-dim random variables, with joint generating function
$$\phi_{X,Y}(s,t)=\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty s^i t^j P(X=i, Y=j), \quad |s|, |t|<1,$$
and their separate generating functions
$$\phi_X(s)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty s^i P(X=i), \quad \phi_Y(t)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty t^j P(Y=j).$$
Prove that $X, Y$ are independent if and only if $\,\phi_{X,Y}(s,t)=\phi_X(s)\phi_Y(t), \,\forall \,|s|, |t|<1$.

The 'only if' part is trivial. For the 'if' part, we get the equation
$$\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty s^i t^j \Big(P(X=i, Y=j) - P(X=i)P(Y=j)\Big), \quad |s|, |t|<1 \\
=:&\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty s^i t^j p_{i,j}
\end{aligned}$$
If the sum is finite, then we can just randomly select a few values of $s,t$ and arrive at a linear equation system w.r.t. $p_{i,j}$ which has only the zero solution, and we're done.
But I cannot figure out how to deal with the countable case. Many thanks in advance.

You have that the power series
$$f(s,t) = \sum s^it^j p_{i,j}$$
is identically zero in a neighbourhood of $s=t=0$, so in particular all its derivatives vanish. But we have:
$$p_{i,j} = \left.\frac{1}{i!j!}\frac{\partial^{i+j}}{\partial^is\partial^jt} f(s,t) \right|_{s=t=0}$$
so we’re done.

Oh... how stubborn I am :(  Thanks!

no problem :-) i only remember this trick bc i spent ages stuck on a similar problem...
